# When can I re-verify auto-renewing subscriptions with Apple?

Tags: ios, app-store, subscriptions, auto-renewing

Say a user purchases a auto-renewing one-month subscription. When can I re-verify the receipt that I'll get a new receipt for the renewed subscription. Do I have to wait exactly 31 days from the time of purchase? Or is 30 days enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify whenever you like and as often as you like. If it's after a renewal has happened you'll get the new receipt in the response. Otherwise you'll just get the receipt from the existing period.